# How to use haml - sass in CakePHP 2.2?

Tags: cakephp, haml, sass, cakephp-2.2

I am trying to follow step given in http://www.travisberry.com/2011/01/haml-sass-markdown-and-cakephp-oh-my/ this link, but it is supposed to be for cake 1.3. I have changed configurations according to cake 2.2. But still not able to use it :(

Please suggest me steps or links which guarantees use of haml and sass in cake. I have also tried chaml but it didnt worked as well.

Thanks

Comment: So what have you tried? What errors do you get?

Comment: I did not get any errors, but cake is not parsing .haml file, it is still parsing .ctp files.

Answer (score 0):

The `$view` attribute is now `$viewClass` in CakePHP 2.x. You also have to change `haml.php` to `HamlView.php`.

The version of `haml.php` you have is probably an old one for <2.0. Pick up the 2.0 version here:

https://raw.github.com/ChrisCinelli/phamlp/master/Cake-2.0/View/haml.php

Comment: And possibly add .haml to the router class for parsing?

Comment: No need, the view class will automatically parse .haml files over .ctp.  Also, you need the updated haml.php view file for CakePHP 2.0 https://raw.github.com/ChrisCinelli/phamlp/master/Cake-2.0/View/haml.php